# sudo apt-get upgrade too slow

Tags: apt

So I wanted to upgrade my Ubuntu packages, so I ran

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it's downloading at less than 10 kbps even though I am using a 4G network. Usually I get speed between 500kbps to 3 mbps.

[image: here's a screenshot of the terminal]

So I wanted to test if it was a network issue, so I played some videos on YouTube in Full HD, they worked fine.

So what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: May be Indian archive is experiencing some issue. Have you tried changing the server?

Comment: Pick and use another mirror - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors - but avoid any that have *last update unknown* as they don't update regularly, and can be slower (are you using one of them?)

Comment: thanks everyone. the download is over. it speeded up on its own later. But this will be useful next time i guess.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, it is probably an issue with Indian Server. 
Just change server to Main server.

Open **Software & Updates**, in section **Ubuntu Server**, and adapt **Download from:** to **Main server**.

You can also open the **Software & Updates** app by running a terminal and enter `software-properties-gtk`

Comment: thanks. The download is already over. it later speeded up on its own. But this will be useful next time.